Browsersync Local host can't be reached
I'm taking this HTML, CSS and Javascript course on Coursera and in this section I'm trying to figure out this issue with browser sync. Following the instructors direction (which are outdated) and the FAQ page doesn't have this question asked.
It was required to use browser-sync and node.js
The instructor did this command:
browser-sync start -- server --directory --files "*"

I followed it and then it produced:
[Browsersync] Copy the following snippet into your website, just before the closing </body> tag

<script id="__bs_script__">
  //<![CDATA[
  (function() {
    try {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      if ('async') {
        script.async = true;
      }
      script.src = 'http://HOST:3000/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=3.0.2'.replace("HOST", location.hostname);
      if (document.body) {
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      } else if (document.head) {
        document.head.appendChild(script);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Browsersync: could not append script tag", e);
    }
  })()
  //]]>
</script>

[Browsersync] Access URLs:
-------------------------------------
UI: http://localhost:3001
-------------------------------------
UI External: http://192.168.56.1:3001
-------------------------------------

I added this to the index.html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hello Coursera!</title>
</head>
<script id="__bs_script__">
  //<![CDATA[
  (function() {
    try {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      if ('async') {
        script.async = true;
      }
      script.src = 'http://HOST:3000/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=3.0.2'.replace("HOST", location.hostname);
      if (document.body) {
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      } else if (document.head) {
        document.head.appendChild(script);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Browsersync: could not append script tag", e);
    }
  })()
  //]]>
</script>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Coursera!</h1>
</body>

</html>

Now it's saying when I copy the URL:
This site can’t be reached  
localhost refused to connect.

Try:   
Checking the connection    
Checking the proxy and the firewall  

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  


Should the URL HOST:3000 be replaced with localhost:3001 from the command output?

replaced host:3000 with localhost:3001 it still has the same error connection message
